# can't enter the IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to solve the Project Euler Problem on the largest palindrome product in Javascript and I don't understand why the program doesn't enter the IF statement `if (number.toString() == number.toString().split('').reverse().join(''))`:

```js
(function palyndrom(max, min) {
    
    top: 
    for (i = max; i > min; i--) {
        for (c = max; c > min; c--) {
            if(i*c == c*i) {
                alert('same was before');
            }
            
            else {
                var number = i*c;
                console.log('i*c = ' + i + '*' + c + ' = ' + number); 
    
//this if not entered, alert doesn't work
                if (number.toString() == number.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) {
                    alert('PALYNDROM FOUND: i*c = ' + i + '*' + c + ' = ' + number);
                    break top;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
})(999, 900);
```

Comment: which if statement? have you tired debugging and tracking the contents of the variables?

Comment: You should fix your errors first. Running your snippet produces at least one.

Comment: You're missing a bracket in there. 6 { and 5 }

Comment: @Jamiec this question involves integers, not floating point values.

Comment: `if(c*i == i*c)` this will always be true, the function will never go to the else part.

Comment: there is one typo.Need one extra } just before, })(999, 900); The for loop is not balanced

Comment: sorry, guys, this is my first time :)
I've added a missing bracket and commented which if is not entered

Comment: @user2181397, how can I balance the for loop?

Comment: @TomekBuszewski He should put back the error. Now running the snippet produces 10,000 alerts.

Answer (score 4):

```
i*c == c*i
```

will always result in true. The function will never reach the else part. I think what you wanted to do is

```
i === c
```

instead:

```
(function palyndrom(max, min) {
top:
    for (var i = max; i > min; i--) {
        for (var c = max; c > min; c--) {
            if (i === c) {
                alert('same was before');
            } else {
                var number = i * c;
                console.log('i*c = ' + i + '*' + c + ' = ' + number);

                if (number.toString() == number.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) {
                    alert('PALYNDROM FOUND: i*c = ' + i + '*' + c + ' = ' + number);
                    break top;
                }
            }
        }

    }
} )(999, 900);
```

Comment: this was made to avoid repetition such as 999*998 and 998*999;

`if (i === c)` it still checks the expressions it has checked before

Comment: @Olga well...it will always be true since there is the [Associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) in maths...the for loop only checks the current values for i and c. If you want to check if you already had the combination of i and c you need to save already checked combinations somewhere. But I would say it's easier to let it run through completely and remove the doubles at the end.

Comment: Since you stop at the first palyndrom anyways there is no need for that kind of checking anyways.

Comment: but it still doubles the expressions, isn't that the thing that we need to avoid?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid when `i == c`? There's nothing in the problem statement that says that the two numbers need to be different.

Comment: I'm thinking of avoiding the situation when one and the same expression is checked twice

Comment: like 999*997 and 997*999

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "}" which results in an error.
Aside from that, i * c is always equal to c * i.
I modified the snippet so that it returns the first palindrome.  The second function returns an array of all of the palindromes.
You don't need to verify that i !== c.

```js
(function palindrome(max, min) {
  for (var i = max; i > min; i--) {
    for (var c = max; c > min; c--) {

      var number = i * c;

      if (number.toString() == number.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) {
        console.log('PALINDROME FOUND: i*c = ' + i + '*' + c + ' = ' + number);
        return number;
      }

    }
  }

})(999, 900);
//PALINDROME FOUND: i*c = 993*913 = 906609
(function palindrome(max, min) {
  var palindromes = {};
  for (var i = max; i > min; i--) {
    for (var c = max; c > min; c--) {

      var number = i * c;

      if (!(number in palindromes) && number.toString() == number.toString().split('').reverse().join('')) {
        palindromes[number] = 1;
      }

    }
  }
  return Object.keys(palindromes);
})(999, 900);
//["819918", "824428", "861168", "886688", "888888", "906609"]
```